# Is there any harm in converting all files to executable?

Tags: unix, file-permissions, chmod

I wanted to install certain software. The package had lots of files including some shell scripting files. Initially I had to select some files and then make it executable:

```
chmod 777 shellscr1
```

but then I realized that there are many such files which I will have to make executable. So as a shortcut, I did this:

```
chmod 777 *
```

and now all the files are executable.

Are there any serious consequences of doing this (apart from security)?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the program, it could have no negative affects or it could make the software unusable.

For example, change the permissions of your ~/.ssh directory and see what error you get when you try and ssh into another machine.

Some programs access config files as a specific user. with 777 permissions, anyone could overwrite the file making *them* the file owner.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by others, there's no reason (at least not presented in the question) why the files would need to be world-writeable. Something like `chmod 755 *` or `chmod +x *` should suffice.

However I will narrow down the answer even more and give you an answer that does *exactly* what you're asking for. A shell script is always expected to begin with a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) such as

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

So here is a snippet that will search for any files in the current directory starting with the characters `#!/` and make those executable. In other word, this command will only mark those files that look like shell scripts as executable.

```
for file in *; do [ "$(head -c 3 "$file")" = '#!/' ] && chmod +x "$file"; done;
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from security there aren't any serious consequences. (speaking logically of course)

Answer (score 0):

> Initially I had to select some files and then make it executable:
>
> ```
>  chmod 777 shellscr1
> ```

Making them executable does not mean *777*, it means *755*. You may at least change this, for obvious reasons connected to security.

Making shell scripts executable may occasionally have some some adverse effects. For instance, if your */bin/sh* points to a different shell than the one the script is intended for, you may make it essentially unusable. A good programmer would have taken steps to prevent that, and by changing permissions you may have voided his efforts.

But, I repeat, this applies only if your /bin/sh points to a non-standard shell.

Comment: That answer is going to confuse the Hell out of people.  It gives the erroneous impression that there's one standard `/bin/sh` and a lot of non-standard `/bin/sh`s.  It also gives the wrong impression that someone nowadays using `#!/bin/sh` is intending a specific shell, a notion that went away in the 1980s-1990s when (POSIX) operating systems that didn't and couldn't have the non-free Bourne shell came about.  There's a way of reading that answer as written such that it's right, but it's not the way that people who don't already know the right answer are going to read it.